# is it possible to explain why this returns 21

Tags: c++

Hello this isn't an assignment or anything but can you explain why this returns 2 1.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void fun(int);
int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        fun(++n);
        cout << n<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could step through the code with a debugger to see it execute line by line. By the way it doesn't *return* 21 (it outputs or prints "2 1" to stdout).

Comment: The sounds like an excellent program to use to familiarize yourself with basic debugger use. With a debugger you can execute the program line by line and watch the variables to see what decisions the program makes and why it made them. Debuggers are an essential tool for the modern programmer and probably second only to the compiler for increasing productivity.

Comment: If you do not have a debugger, use what you know of C++ to execute each line in your very own CPU, the Mark 1 brain, on a piece of paper.

Comment: but is it possible to explain this for me while I figure out how to use a debugger

Comment: It doesn't really return `21`, it outputs `2`, then `1`.

Comment: that was a typo on my part I know it doesn't print 21 you can see under the question I put 2 space and then 1 to show that

Comment: @HabHab I think 500 is refering to the sloppy but common usage of 'return' to mean 'print', not to any missing spaces.

Comment: Note: you can visualize this code at http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit. Select the gcc C++ compiler from the dropdown, paste in your code, add `#include <iostream>` so that it compiles cleanly, then click Visualize Execution.

Comment: Because it first calls recursion and after that it prints the variable. If you print variable before calling recursion it will print 1 then 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Flow of `fun()` :

1. You are passing `a` which is initialized to 0 as the parameter to the `fun()`. So, You call `fun(0)` from `main()`.
2. In the call `fun(0)` the condition `n<2` is true since at the start, it is 0. So the function `fun(0)` will
   call `fun(++n)`,that is `fun(1)` and push the current function call on the stack. **Notice, the value of n in the function call which is pushed has increased to 1.**
3. Again, `n<2` evaluates to true since now the value of n is 1. The
   function will call `fun(++n)` again, that is `fun(2)` and push the current function call to stack once again.**Notice, the value of n in the function call which is pushed has increased to 2.**
4. Now, the value of n is 2 and hence `n<2` evaluates to false. So,
   this time it will not do anything and just terminate
5. Now, the last function call will get popped from stack and `cout` will get executed. So, the control returns to the function at the top of the stack, which in our case is `fun(1)`. But, here we had increased our `n` by doing `++n` (Check point : 3). So the value printed will be 2. This function call now gets terminated.
6. Now, at the top of stack is the function call that we pushed at first, that is `fun(0)` but our value of n was increased by `++n` (Check point : 2). So now the value of n which is 1 will be printed.

Hope you understand the above explanation and this solves your doubt !

Comment: 1 question why do you say stack

Comment: @HabHab In recursion, each time a function calls itself, the current function call is pushed onto the stack and the recursive call is made. When the called function finishes, the function which was pushed onto the stack gets popped off and continues its execution. This is the process that happens behind every recursion.

Comment: @HabHab You need to learn how to use the debugger.  The debugger should have a window called the "call stack", this is the internal stack of the executing thread that Abhishek is talking about.  When you hit a breakpoint in the debugger, this window will show you the recursive call stack, along with the value of the parameter n for each call on the "stack".  The "call stack" is a wonderful tool for both debugging and for understanding code.  Sometimes I just set a breakpoint at a line of code and then look at the debugger's call stack just to understand HOW that method is being called.

Answer (score 2):

You can think about recursion as nesting the functions inside of each other.

You pass n = 0.

```
fun(n=0)
{
    if (0 < 2)
    {
        // ++n alters n to be equal to n+1 for our current scope.
        fun(++n); // n = 1 now, fun gets called with n = 1
        {
            fun(n=1)
            {
                if (1 < 2)
                {
                    fun(++n); // n = 2 now, fun gets called with n = 2
                    {
                        fun(2)
                        {
                            if(2 < 2) // returns false
                        } 
                    } // we exit this scope without doing anything futher
                    cout << n << " "; // n = 2 in this scope, here we print the 2
                }
            }
        } // now we exit this scope
        cout << n<<" "; // n = 1 in this scope, here we print the 1
    }
}
```

Please let me know how I can clarify this further.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not *return* anything, except for the `main` function that returns 0 exit code. The function `fun` just *prints*.

It prints `2 1`, because it computes this:

```
void fun0()
{
   fun1();
   cout << 1 <<" ";
}

void fun1()
{
   cout << 2 <<" ";
}
```

Therefore it first prints 2 and then prints 1 after the code returns from `fun1`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make a recursive call a new instance of n will be created. The program will only reach the first cout after two recursive calls, so n will be 2 at that point. I don't want to explain how everything works in detail, I genuinely think that if you write some more printf's you will be able to figure out what the program is doing by yourself. If you figure this out by yourself with my simple hints you'll know how recursion works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly function will not return anything until you add a return statement in the function, In your case you are not returning the value, you wrote a statement to print/display the current value of 'n' initially you set a=0 and calling a function "fun(a)" and passing the value of "a" So, in the "fun" function you added a condition which says the value of "n" should be smaller than "2", then you are using the recursive method(a function that calls itself) and pre incrementing "++n" the value of "n" and passing it in the fun function.

```
n = 0
fun(n)

fun(0){

if (n < 2) *first call true

    {
        fun(++n); *n = 1 before going to next condition it is calling itself*
        cout << 1<<" "; 
    }

}
fun(1){

if (n < 2) *true*

    {
        fun(++n); *n = 2 again before going to next condition it is calling itself*
        cout << 2<<" ";
    }

}
fun(2){

if (n < 2) *flase*

    {
        fun(++n);
        cout << n<<" ";
    }

}
```

So, it will print 2 and then 1.
[flow of Recursive function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1y7z.png)

I hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

fun() is a non tail recursion call and base condition is n<2 then
fun will call twice fun(0) &fun(1). As recursion activation record maintain on stack then while reaching at base condition it will print

2 1
Cout "2"
Cout "1"

I will recommend please go through recursion concept thoroughly.